# How to access exported function from a library in a service class in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Sorry for what might be an obvious question for some but I am mostly experienced with back-end technology so my intuition so far hasn't helped and neither could I come up with the perfect wording to let google help me.

I have an angular library where a couple of helper functions are exported but I can't call them from inside a class in the file I import it in. Though it is available just outside the class. How can I make it accessible inside the class?

The library which exports the function:

```
export function saveAs(data: string | Blob, fileName: string, options?: SaveOptions): void;
```

The class where I import it:

```
import * as FileSaver from '@progress/kendo-file-saver'

const dataURI = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa("Hello World!");
//Below function call is resolved
FileSaver.saveAs(dataURI, 'test.txt', {       
    forceProxy: true,
    proxyURL: '/save-handler',
   });

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class FileProxyService {
 
    constructor (){}
    private base64 ;
    
   //Below function call is not recognized
   FileSaver.saveAs(dataURI, 'test.txt', {            
    forceProxy: true,
    proxyURL: '/save-handler',
   });
}
```

Comment: It was pretty obvious in the end. The call was directly in the body of a class. Moving it into a constructor or any function fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use an exported function/method from a different source you need to inject the object to your current ts-file.

Import the kendo-file-saver:

```
    import { FileSaver } from '@progress/kendo-file-saver';
```

and change your constructor like this:

```
    constructor(private fileSaver:FileSaver) {}
```

Now you have an (injected) Object of the Filesaver named fileSaver and you can use its SaveAs-method

```
    fileSaver.SaveAs(dataURI, 'test.txt', { 
    forceProxy: true,
    proxyURL: 'save-handler', });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I noticed I didn't paste the correct import statement which I edited right now. FileSaver is not a class but just an alias to the exported functions in the library that I am importing in my service class. As such it can't be injected or instantiated.